# Looking for a MyBatis plugin for IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: intellij-idea, mybatis

I'm looking for a current MyBatis plugin for IntelliJ Idea 14. I previously used one hosted by Seventh7 but that is no longer listed (and its git is a 404). The main thing I'm looking for is decent linking between my classes that extend SqlSessionDaoSupport (my DAO classes) and their matching xml files (not using annotation driven).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hope this helps idea-mini-ibatis https://github.com/ishchenko/idea-mini-ibatis works for mybatis

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the latest free version was v2.34 and it was applied to IDEA v141.177 till v141.179 (as described in file plugin.xml inside jar). That's why this plugin is no listed in IDEA. After this author released paid version and  closes free access to the repo
  But there is a free fork here:

- https://github.com/phoenix/intellij-mybatis-plugin (I love github and open source :) )

Short instruction how to install it:

- Download intellij-mybatis-plugin.jar from repo above or use [direct link](https://github.com/Chris-V/intellij-mybatis-plugin/blob/master/intellij-mybatis-plugin.jar?raw=true)
- In  IDEA: File>Settings>Plugins, press button "Install plugin from disk" and select  downloaded jar.
- Restart IDEA

Note: For me navigation to and from xml files does not work until I disabled another iBatis plugin

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij, Go to Settings-->Plugin-->Browse repositories

Search for mybatis plugin.
Install it and restart.

Comment: take note there is a free one and there is one which you will need to pay

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin named MyBatisCodeHelperPro, you can search it in repositories.
or download via https://github.com/gejun123456/MyBatisCodeHelper-Pro/blob/master/README_EN.md